# How to set up Azure Batch pool container configuration via ARM template?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-rm-template, azure-batch

We are using Azure Batch, and we need to use Windows Docker containers on the VMs.

This is how it is done via Portal:
[image: containers via portal]

And this is how it is done via C# API:

```cs
private static VirtualMachineConfiguration ConfigureVM()
{
    var imageNames = new List<string> { "microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7" };
    var containerConfig = new ContainerConfiguration
    {
        ContainerImageNames = imageNames
    };

    var offer = "WindowsServer";
    var publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer";
    var imageSku = "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers";
    var imageReference = new ImageReference(offer, publisher, imageSku);

    var nodeSku = "batch.node.windows amd64";
    var vmConfig = new VirtualMachineConfiguration(imageReference, nodeSku)
    {
        ContainerConfiguration = containerConfig
    };

    return vmConfig;
}
```

And now we are automating deployment so I want to do the same via ARM template (*this is a child resource of the Azure Batch account, so name and type are ok*):

```json
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "type": "pools",
        "apiVersion": "2017-09-01",
        "properties": {
            "vmSize": "STANDARD_A1",
            "deploymentConfiguration": {
                "virtualMachineConfiguration": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                        "offer": "WindowsServer",
                        "sku": "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers"
                    },
                    "nodeAgentSkuId": "batch.node.windows amd64",
                    "containerConfiguration": {
                        "imageNames": [ "microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And this does not work. When deploying, I get:

```
Could not find member 'containerConfiguration' on object of type 'VirtualMachineConfiguration'. 
Path 'properties.deploymentConfiguration.virtualMachineConfiguration.containerConfiguration'
```

Without `containerConfiguration` part things work - I get VMs with docker, just without the image. I understand why this happens - the template [does not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.batch/batchaccounts/pools#virtualmachineconfiguration-object) have this property as opposed to .NET [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.virtualmachineconfiguration?view=azure-dotnet#properties).

So... any workaround? I guess it is not the first time when template is not synced with functionality.

Comment: Can you tell me the `type` you are using? I am facing the same problem now. I would appreciate if you could post a solution if you found one.

Comment: Rustam, `type` of what? We have not found a direct solution, our workaround is a crazy command line in the start task, where we login to docker and pull the image.

Comment: `type` of the resource that says `pools` in your case. I have solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: Okay. FWIW, it is `Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts`, if I get you right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a recent update the ARM provider for Batch was improved to allow creation of a container enabled pool. The following ARM template will create a container pool, notice the API version is updated.

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts/pools",
            "name": "[concat(variables('batchAccountName'), '/', parameters('poolID'))]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-12-01",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]",
                "networkConfiguration": {
                    "subnetId": "[parameters('virtualNetworkSubnetId')]"
                },
                "maxTasksPerNode": 1,
                "taskSchedulingPolicy": {
                    "nodeFillType": "Spread"
                },
                "deploymentConfiguration": {
                    "virtualMachineConfiguration": {
                        "containerConfiguration": {
                            "containerImageNames": "[parameters('dockerImagesToCache')]",
                            "type": "DockerCompatible"
                        },
                        "imageReference": {
                            "publisher": "microsoft-azure-batch",
                            "offer": "ubuntu-server-container",
                            "sku": "16-04-lts",
                            "version": "latest"
                        },
                        "nodeAgentSkuId": "batch.node.ubuntu 16.04"
                    }
                },
                "scaleSettings": {
                    "autoScale": {
                        "evaluationInterval": "PT5M",
                        "formula": "[concat('startingNumberOfVMs = 0;maxNumberofVMs = ', parameters('maxNodeCount'), ';pendingTaskSamplePercent = $PendingTasks.GetSamplePercent(160 * TimeInterval_Second);pendingTaskSamples = pendingTaskSamplePercent < 70 ? startingNumberOfVMs : avg($PendingTasks.GetSample(160 * TimeInterval_Second));$TargetDedicatedNodes=min(maxNumberofVMs, pendingTaskSamples);')]"
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts', variables('batchAccountName'))]"
            ]
        }
```

----- Previous Answer now not needed -----

I've managed to find a workaround using an ACI container along with Managed Service Identities and some Python. It's not pretty but it does work.

The flow of the template is as follows:

1. An MSI is created
2. The MSI is assigned contributor rights for the resource group
3. The Batch account is created
4. An ACI instance is run which pulls down a templated `pool.json` file and uses a python script to fill in the required parameters. The python logs in to the `az cli` using the MSI identity then proceeds to create the pool.

Here is the full setup, you'll likely want to tweak this to fit your scenario.

The python script and `pool.json` file need to be uploaded to a public location, such as blob storage or git, then the `_artifactLocation` parameters are used to tell the template where to download the files.

Main template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "_artifactsLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": ""
            }
        },
        "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": ""
            }
        },
        "mountArgs": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Arguments passed to the mount.py script."
            }
        },
        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The subnet in which Batch will be deployed. Requires the following ports to be enabled via NSG: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-virtual-network#network-security-groups-1."
            }
        },
        "maxTasksPerNode": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 1
        },
        "maxNodeCount": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 3
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_F8s_v2",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Size of VMs in the VM Scale Set."
            }
        },
        "storageAccountSku": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard_LRS",
                "Standard_GRS",
                "Standard_ZRS",
                "Premium_LRS"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Storage Account type"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        },
        "poolId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "defaultpool"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "identityName": "batchpoolcreator",
        "storageAccountName": "[concat('batch', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
        "batchAccountName": "[concat('batch', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
        "batchEndpoint": "[concat('https://', variables('batchAccountName'), '.' , parameters('location'), '.batch.azure.com')]",

        "_comment": "The role assignment ID is required to be a guid, we use this to generate a repeatable guid",
        "roleAssignmentIdRg": "[guid(concat(resourceGroup().id, 'contributorRG'))]",

        "_comment": "This is the ID used to set the contributor permission on a role.",
        "contributorRoleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "Create an identity to use for creating the Azure Batch pool with container support (will be assigned to ACI instance)",
            "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
            "name": "[variables('identityName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-31-preview",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        },
        {
            "comments": "Assign the idenity contributor rights to the resource group",
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
            "name": "[variables('roleAssignmentIdRg')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('contributorRoleDefinitionId')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName')), '2015-08-31-preview').principalId]",
                "scope": "[resourceGroup().id]"
            }
        },
        {
            "comments": "This is the storage account used by Azure Batch for file processing/storage",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountname')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('storageAccountsku')]"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "tags": {
                "ObjectName": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
            },
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts",
            "name": "[variables('batchAccountName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2015-12-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "ObjectName": "[variables('batchAccountName')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "autoStorage": {
                    "storageAccountId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
            "name": "[substring(concat('batchpool', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)), 0, 20)]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName'))]",
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments', variables('roleAssignmentIdRg'))]",
              "[resourceId('Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts', variables('batchAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "identity": {
              "type": "UserAssigned",
              "userAssignedIdentities": {
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName'))]": {}
              }
            },
            "properties": {
              "osType": "Linux",
              "restartPolicy": "Never",
              "containers": [
                {
                  "name": "azure-cli",
                  "properties": {
                    "image": "microsoft/azure-cli",
                    "command": [
                      "/bin/bash",
                      "-c",
                      "[concat('curl -fsSL ', parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/azurebatch/configurepool.py', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'), ' > configurepool.py && python3 ./configurepool.py \"', parameters('poolId'), '\" ', parameters('virtualMachineSize'),  ' \"', parameters('mountArgs'),  '\" ', parameters('_artifactsLocation'),  ' ', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'),  ' ', parameters('virtualNetworkSubnetId'), ' ', parameters('maxNodeCount'), ' ', resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('identityName')), ' ', resourceGroup().name, ' ', variables('batchAccountName'))]"
                    ],
                    "resources": {
                      "requests": {
                        "cpu": 1,
                        "memoryInGB": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
      }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
        },
        "batchAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('batchAccountName')]"
        },
        "batchEndpoint": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('batchEndpoint')]"
        },
        "batchAccountKey": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Batch/batchAccounts', variables('batchAccountName')), '2017-09-01').primary]"
        },
        "batchPoolId": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('poolId')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Pool.json

```
{
    "id": "POOL_ID_HERE",
    "vmSize": "VM_SIZE_HERE",
    "enableAutoScale": true,
    "autoScaleFormula": "startingNumberOfVMs = 0;maxNumberofVMs = MAX_NODE_COUNT_HERE;pendingTaskSamplePercent = $PendingTasks.GetSamplePercent(160 * TimeInterval_Second);pendingTaskSamples = pendingTaskSamplePercent < 70 ? startingNumberOfVMs : avg($PendingTasks.GetSample(160 * TimeInterval_Second));$TargetDedicatedNodes=min(maxNumberofVMs, pendingTaskSamples);",
    "autoScaleEvaluationInterval": "PT5M",
    "enableInterNodeCommunication": false,
    "startTask": {
        "commandLine": "/usr/bin/python3 mount.py MOUNT_ARGS_HERE",
        "resourceFiles": [
            {
                "blobSource": "ARTIFACT_LOCATION_HERE/examplemountscript/script.pyARTIFACT_SAS_HERE",
                "filePath": "./mount.py",
                "fileMode": "777"
            }
        ],
        "userIdentity": {
            "autoUser": {
                "scope": "pool",
                "elevationLevel": "admin"
            }
        },
        "maxTaskRetryCount": 0,
        "waitForSuccess": true
    },
    "maxTasksPerNode": 1,
    "taskSchedulingPolicy": {
        "nodeFillType": "Spread"
    },
    "virtualMachineConfiguration": {
        "containerConfiguration": {
            "containerImageNames": [
                "ubuntu",
                "python"
            ]
        },
        "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "microsoft-azure-batch",
            "offer": "ubuntu-server-container",
            "sku": "16-04-lts",
            "version": "1.0.6"
        },
        "nodeAgentSKUId": "batch.node.ubuntu 16.04"
    },
    "networkConfiguration": {
        "subnetId": "SUBNET_ID_HERE"
    }
}
```

configurepool.py:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import urllib.request


def run_az_command(cmdArray):
    try:
        print("Attempt run {}".format(cmdArray))
        subprocess.check_call(cmdArray)
        print("Install completed successfully")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Failed running: {} error: {}".format(cmdArray, e))
        exit(4)

if len(sys.argv) != 11:
    print(
        "Expected 'poolid', 'vm_size', 'mount_args', 'artifact_location', 'artifact_sas', 'subnet_id', 'max_node_count', 'msi_name', 'resource_group_name' , 'batch_account_name'"
    )
    exit(1)

pool_id = str(sys.argv[1])
vm_size = str(sys.argv[2])
mount_args = str(sys.argv[3])
artifact_location = str(sys.argv[4])
artifact_sas = str(sys.argv[5])
subnet_id = str(sys.argv[6])
max_node_count = str(sys.argv[7])
msi_name = str(sys.argv[8])
resource_group_name = str(sys.argv[9])
batch_account_name = str(sys.argv[10])

url = "{0}/azurebatch/pool.json{1}".format(artifact_location, artifact_sas)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()
text = data.decode("utf-8") 

# Replace the target string
text = text.replace("POOL_ID_HERE", pool_id)
text = text.replace("VM_SIZE_HERE", vm_size)
text = text.replace("MOUNT_ARGS_HERE", mount_args)
text = text.replace("ARTIFACT_LOCATION_HERE", artifact_location)
text = text.replace("ARTIFACT_SAS_HERE", artifact_sas)
text = text.replace("SUBNET_ID_HERE", subnet_id)
text = text.replace("MAX_NODE_COUNT_HERE", max_node_count)


# Write the file out again
with open("pool.complete.json", "w") as file:
    file.write(text)

run_az_command(["az", "login", "--identity", "-u", msi_name])
run_az_command(["az", "batch", "account", "login", "--name", batch_account_name, "-g", resource_group_name])
run_az_command(["az", "batch", "pool", "create", "--json-file", "pool.complete.json"])
```